PDAL command: passing pipeline definition instead of path to file
A pdal pipeline command can be run as:
pdal pipeline --input path/to/pipeline.json

I want to run this command using Java's ProcessBuilder, and pipeline has to be defined using some user inputs. So I first write pipeline string to a file and then use that file path in command above, which seems to be lots of work.
Is it possible that instead of passing path to json file in above command, we pass it the pipeline definition directly as string?
